# Textbox in Listview not expand until hover a mouse over it

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, uwp

So I have a list that loads a data from a list of string.

I want to make it editable, So I make a ListView of Textbox.

Somewhat like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind texts, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text={Binding, Mode=TwoWay}>
            <Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that when the list is loaded. If it already has a text. It collapsed.

[Here's a picture for the context..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRUz0.png)

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you can add a placeholder for the TextBox.

Comment: have you tried setting a ```MinHeight``` on it?

Comment: @Rafael That work, thank you.

Comment: @ToonWK glad to hear. I'll add that as an answer and you can mark it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `MinHeight` on the `TextBox` element should fix the problem.